# Javascript hide body on button click and show on window click

Tags: javascript, html

I have this bit of Javascript/HTML code which will hide the body on the HTML page when the button is pressed:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="android.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body class="services">
<div id="container">
<nav class="top">
    <a href="user.html">User</a>
    <a class="active" href="shop.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="staff.html">Staff</a>
</nav>
<h1>Shop Details</h1>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="Great" value="Great">Great<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Good" value="Good">Good<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Satisfactory" value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory<br />
    <input type="radio" name="BelowAverage" value="BelowAverage">Below Average<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Poor" value="poor">Poor<br />
    <textarea placeholder="Comments to go here" rows="8" cols="33"></textarea>
</form>
<h1>Cleanliness</h1>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="Great" value="Great">Great<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Good" value="Good">Good<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Satisfactory" value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory<br />
    <input type="radio" name="BelowAverage" value="BelowAverage">Below      Average<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Poor" value="poor">Poor<br />
    <textarea placeholder="Comments to go here" rows="8" cols="33"></textarea>
</form>
<h1>Retail interaction</h1>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="Great" value="Great">Great<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Good" value="Good">Good<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Satisfactory" value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory<br />
    <input type="radio" name="BelowAverage" value="BelowAverage">Below Average<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Poor" value="poor">Poor<br />
    <textarea placeholder="Comments to go here" rows="8" cols="33"></textarea>
</form>
</div>
<nav class="bottomFixed">
    <a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="hide" href="#" onclick="hideDoc();">Hide</a>
</nav>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideDoc() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display="none";

}
</script>
```

What I want is when the window is clicked or touched (must be able to work with touch screen devices) after enabling the function via the button, the body tag will display again.

Comment: its not possible.. so you have to use <div> under <body> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

`window.onclick = function() { 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display="";
}`

And you should insert your `<script>`s in the `<head>`!

Here is an example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brJn8/2/)

Comment: why `window.onclick `??

Comment: because you want to do it when you click the window, right? I wouldn't hide the body tough...

Comment: I tried putting this bit of code (copy and pasted) after the function, it did not work.

Comment: Also moved the javascript into the head

Comment: Setting the `display` to `block` may cause some unwanted behavior, use empty string instead which will use the default behavior.

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display="";`

Comment: You're right. Fixed it. @Simon I've added little example to my answer. Have a look

Comment: If I use window.click, won't it make my other function irrelevant because you have to click the button in the first place?